# how i can creat a array of vector saving arrays of which size is 2 in java?

Tags: java, arrays, vector

i want to create a array of (vector of (arrays that size 2)) like

```
Vector<Integer[2]>[]
```

i tried

```
Vector<Integer[]>[] arr2 = new Vector[5];

for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
  arr2[i] = new Vector<Integer[]>();
}
int[] arr = {1,5};
arr2[0].add(arr);
```

but it have a error

```
The method add(Integer[]) in the type Vector<Integer[]> is not applicable for the arguments (int[])
```

is it possible convert int[] to Integer[] or create vector with int[] instead of Integer[]?

how can i create this??

Comment: `int` and `Integer` can autobox and un-box into one another, but `int[]` and `Integer[]` are two different object types, as they are array types. You can either make your `Vector` for `int[]`s or declare your `arr` as `Integer[]`. Inserting `int`s into either array type should work due to autoboxing.

Comment: Why do you need this usage. Vector is considered as [absolute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way to declare/use it:

```
Vector<int[]> arr2 = new Vector<int[]>();//Correct declaration syntax

int[] arr = {1,5};
for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
     arr2.add(arr);
}
```

You can either do that with `Integer`, but not mix them:

```
Vector<Integer[]> arr2 = new Vector<Integer[]>();

Integer[] arr = {1,5};
for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
     arr2.add(arr);
}
```

Comment: ... thanks you! i thought i have to use <Integer> to make int vector

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 Integer[] arr = { 1, 5 };
arr2[0].add(arr);
```

I suggest to remain with Integer if you want to treat null values

Comment: oh it's first time use Integer like variable. i will try it also. thank you